# When do I need np.frompyfunc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Please, consider the following code below:

```
import numpy as np

def one_plus_square(x):
  return 1+x**2
one_plus_square_vectorized = np.frompyfunc(one_plus_square,1,1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], np.float16)

    #Both codes below present the same result?
    one_plus_square(A)
    one_plus_square_vectorized(A)
```

It is not clear for me when we should use `np.frompyfunc`

It seems for me that both codes with and without provide the same result. Are there any differences? Why should I include that extra piece of code? Can you give an example when this is really necessary?

It seems that this might be related with the speed of the code. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This (and `np.vectorize`) is an aid when the function can only accept scalar arguments.  For example if has `if` tests.  It's an alternative to using a list comprehension, or nested for loops, to apply the function to each element of an array.  Speed is about the same.  Better yet if the function takes several inputs, and you'd like to `broadccast` arrays on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two functions seem identical because `return 1 + x**2` is *already* a vectorized operation: All the operators in the expression use vectorized implementations that operate on the entire array. A better example would be if your function was something that wasn't vectorized, e.g. if we wanted to use the `bin` pyfunc to get the binary representation of all integers in an array:

```
bin_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(bin, 1, 1)
```

is the equivalent to:

```
def bin_iter(x):
    a = []
    for i in x:
        a.append(bin(i))

    return np.array(a)
```

As another example, if you wanted to calculate the number of binary digits in each element of an array, but for some reason didn't want to do it using logarithms, you could define a function that does it for one number:

```
def bit_length(i):
    return len(bin(i)) - 2
```

And then create a `ufunc` out of it:

```
bit_length_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(bit_length, 1, 1)
```

Now the `ufunc` automatically broadcasts over arrays of any shape:

```
>>> bit_length_ufunc(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2))
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]], dtype=object)
```

**Note that the `ufunc` created by `frompyfunc` always returns an array of python objects, which are not as optimized for vector operations as arrays of numpy primitive types like `int64`**

Also note that this **doesn't give any speed advantage**, since at the end of the day your python function needs to be called. See the note in the [documentation for `np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

This can be verified by using `timeit.timeit` to compare the performance for two 1d arrays. First, let's define a function which dooes the equivalent of `bit_length_ufunc` using a loop

```
def bit_length_loop(arr):
    r = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=int)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        r[i] = len(bin(arr[i])) - 2

    return r
```

And timing this gives:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> timeit('bit_length_ufunc(arr)', globals=globals(), number=1_000_000)
1.6345342000001892
>>> timeit('bit_length_ufunc(arr)', globals=globals(), number=1_000_000)
2.012084499999901
```

Additionally, remember that
[`frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) returns a [`np.ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.html#numpy.ufunc) which has certain features over python functions.

For example, if (for some weird reason) you wanted to replace the alternate indices of an array with the bit length, you could use [`ufunc.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)**2
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])

>>> indices_to_replace = np.arange(0, 10, 2)
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

>>> bit_length_ufunc.at(arr, indices_to_replace)
array([ 1,  1,  3,  9,  5, 25,  6, 49,  7, 81])
```

Comment: It's even more of a help if the function takes several inputs, and you  want to take advantage of broadcasting to apply it to several arrays.